# Stack and heap in C#

Tags: c#, heap-memory, stack-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [What and where are the stack and heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

There is a difference in C# between the heap and stack. I've just realized that I always thought that the stack is RAM and the heap is a hard drive. But now I'm not sure if it's correct. If it isn't, then what's is the difference if they are stored in one place?

Answer (score 13):

"The stack" (or more precisely the call stack) is automatically managed memory (even in "unmanaged languages" like C): Local variables are stored on the stack in stack frames that also contain the procedures or functions arguments and the return address and maybe some machine-specific state that needs to be restored upon return.

Heap memory is that part of RAM (or rather: virtual address space) used to satisfy dynamic memory allocations (`malloc` in C).

Yet, in C# heap and stack usage is an implementation detail. In practice though, objects of reference type are heap-allocated; value type data can both be stored on the stack and on the heap, depending on the context (e.g. if it's part of an reference-type object).